# How to save objects in room the database. Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, typeconverter

I'm trying to save objects in the room database.

My profile object class that I want to save in the database:

```
class Profile(
 val exampleString : String = "Example String",
 val exampleStringTwo : String = "Example String Two",
 val subObjectsList : ArrayList<SubObjecst> = ArrayList()
)
```

Profile object include Arraylist of Subobjects with this structure:

```
class SubObjects(    
  val exampleString : String = "Example 1",
  val exampleStringTwo : String = "Example 2",
  val exampleStringThree: String = "Example 3"    
  )


data class ProfileEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "profile") var profille: Profile
) : Parcelable
```

How to save Profile object in the room database? I'm stuck on the Type converter for this object.

Comment: Convert object to `JSON` `String` by using `GSON` library.

Answer (score 0):

### Using a `TypeConverter`

Type converters are really for converting simple types, say a date or enum value, however it could be used for this case. You would need to have some way converting your `SubObject` to a `String`, probably with some sort of delimiter that you are confident doesn't exist in your object fields already. So something like:

```
fun SubObject.toString() = "$exampleString@@$exampleString2@@$exampleString3"
```

However this doesn't really leverage what SQL is for, which is column-based data.

### Using Relationships

This is probably the method you want. By having a separate `Entity` for your `Profile` and `SubObject` models, you can then query the database to return the relationship between your `Profile` and `SubObject`, specifically in a **one-to-many relationship**. In Room, this is implemented using the `@Embedded` and `@Relation` annotations. I would recommend taking a look at the Android Devleopers documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships) but for your example you want something like this:

```
class ResolvedProfile(
    @Embedded
    val profile: Profile,
    @Relation(parentColumn = "profileId", entityColumn = "subObjectProfileId")
    val subObjects: List<SubObject>
)
```